# Meteor: Preselected options lost after rerendering multiple select

Tags: meteor

I have a multiple select with a Handlebar template in Meteor.js. On first rendering, everything is fine ("Politics" and "People" are preselected as expected):

[image: Multiple select on first render]

As soon as the template has to be rerendered (because a Session variable changes, e.g. `Session.set("foo", "Hello World!")`), the third option is not preselected anymore:

[image: Multiple select after dynamic changes]

My setup:

```html
<template name="select">
  <select name="foo" multiple>
    <option value="1">Tech</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Politics</option>
    <option value="3" selected>People</option>
  </select>
</template>

<template name="test">
  {{foo}}
  {{> select}}
</template>

{{> test}}
```

```
Template.test.helpers(
  foo: ->
    Session.get("foo")
)
```

Do you have any idea why the options are preselected anymore after rerendering?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:

```
<template name="test">
  {{#isolate}}
    {{foo}}
  {{/isolate}}      
  {{> select}}
</template>
```

> Typically, the exact extent of re-rendering is not crucial, but if you
>   want more control, such as for performance reasons, you can use the
>   {{#isolate}}...{{/isolate}} helper. Data dependencies established
>   inside an #isolate block are localized to the block and will not in
>   themselves cause the parent template to be re-rendered. This block
>   helper essentially conveys the reactivity benefits you would get by
>   pulling the content out into a new sub-template.

If you put `{{foo}}` inside `{{#isolate}} ... {{/isolate}}` then parent template won't be rerendered, so also `{{> select}}` won't be affected.

Comment: Cool, it is working! Do you know why rerendering of the multiple select doesn't work, since it is working with normal selects. Could this be a bug, or is this expected behavior?

Comment: I extracted the code into a new meteor project, and filed a bug at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1274 .

Comment: Mh, I think the ```{{#isolate}}``` "hack" doesn't help me when the select template depends on reactive data source, too (e.g. something like ```<option value="1" {{#ifSelected "1"}}selected{{/if}}>...</option>```. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Package called preserve-inputs takes care about keeping state of input after rerendering. That plugin is remembering only one selection - the last one selected. Under the hood preserve-inputs set Spark._globalPreserves[selector] = Spark._labelFromIdOrName; Conclusion is that Spark package doesn't take care of preserve selections in multiselect case

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure why you are loosing the multiple select but I can recommend you put an `{{#isolate}}` tag around your`{{> select}}` template. That should keep the template from re-rendered. Though it will not help if your select template re-renders because its data changes. Hope that helps...